# Comparison method violates its general contract! (elements duplicated in collection during sort)

Tags: java, sorting, duplicates, comparator, timsort

I know there are many topics with same subject, but this case seems to me a bit different and not well-documented in javadocs. Here is the code:

```
Random random = new Random(0);

var list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    list.add(random.nextInt());
}

list.sort((x, y) -> {
    int sum = list.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);

    System.out.println(sum);

    return Integer.compare(x + sum, y + sum);
});
```

The result is exception:

```
-1303811196
-1303811196
.....
-1303811196
-1303811196
-1303811196
-1364558868
-1569607140
-1836181454
-2014724660
-2023409163
-2094470032
-2128134715
2107317277
2107317277
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:781)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:518)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:448)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1516)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1717)
    at HomeWork6_4.Company.main(Company.java:131)
```

So it seems like, it's not possible to rely on collection during sorting, because its in dirty state. Is that behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: You should probably move the `sum` variable out of the lambda

Comment: It is possible to rely on collection during sorting, The behavior is documented [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/compatibility.html), quoting "The new sort implementation may throw an IllegalArgumentException if it detects a Comparable that violates the Comparable contract." Which it does detect, since you provide it with a non-transitive comparator.

Comment: I think the question being asked is whether it is possibly to rely on the contents of the collection having some relationship to the original collection in the midst of the sort, such as having the same elements though perhaps in a different order. The answer is *no* it is not possible to rely on that property. The sort can be done in-place, and the sorting is not simply done by swapping elements (as is done in, say, a selection sort). Instead, elements are merged to and from temporary arrays, which may result in elements temporarily being duplicated or missing during the sort.

Comment: Would it be helpful if this behavior were documented?

Comment: @StuartMarks Yes, I will find it helpfull :) I faced that problem on larger project, the code was surely more complex than in demo above, and it looked valid, written in pretty functional style with almost no state (except sorting :). Java docs didn't helped me, so the only way to find that was to spend some time in debugger.

Comment: @IgorAvdeev OK, thanks for the feedback. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

Let us debug by logging what the Comparator is doing internally. For that, I am adding a special logging method to track the results of the comparator. Please check the code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random(0);
    
    var list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        list.add(random.nextInt());
    }
    list.sort(logging((x, y) -> {
        int sum = list.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
        return Integer.compare(x + sum, y + sum);
    }));
}

public static Comparator<Integer> logging(Comparator<Integer> c) {
    return (Integer a, Integer b)-> {
        int r = c.compare(a, b);
        System.err.printf("%7d  %7d => %2d%n", a, b, r);
        return r;
    };
}
```

The behaviour of Comparator for two inputs (T a, T b) is following

```
(i) returns  less than 0 ,  means a<b
(ii)returns 0 , means a==b
(iii)return greater than 0 , means a>b
```

If any comparator doesn't satisfy these rules, we say the comparator is broken.
Now let's pay close attention to what the comparator is logging

```
-723955400  -1155484576 => -1  // broken (a>b but comparator Integer.compare(a+sum,b+sum) returned less than 0)
1033096058  -723955400 =>  1   // broken 
1033096058  -1155484576 => -1
1033096058  -723955400 =>  1
-1690734402  1033096058 =>  1. // broken
```

This shows that the specific comparator you used `Integer.compare(a+sum, b+sum)` has overflown and resulted in the inconsistent result when you apply against the list elements. When such a broken comparator is used sort(c) throws such Exception.